# Binding a UserControl to a ListBox ItemSource

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have an ObservableCollection that has a list of objects.

I would like to bind this observable collection to the ListBox but not in a way that each object gets shown inside the ListView, but instead that Each object creates a UserControl that has the object itself as input parameter.

To give a similar example; imagine a server browser where each line is a UserControl and data is stored in a List/ObservableCollection and then displayed inside a frontend ListBox.

I have this XAML code in my MainWindow.xaml

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" ItemsSource="{Binding Bills}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource BillStyle}">
</ListBox>
```

And this is the style that invokes the UserControl

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}" x:Key="BillStyle">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                <ns:BillItem />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and in the MainWindow.xaml.cs I have:

```
ObservableCollection<Bill> Bills {get;set;}
```

And inside the constructor I just added few objects.

I would like that the Bill object gets pushed to the User Control in this manner:

```
UserControl BillItem (Bill BindedObject)
{ ... }
```

But I don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, you need something like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ListOfObjects}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:MyUserControl MyProperty="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

MyUserControl needs to have dependency property, because you cant pass to constructor:

```
public object MyProperty
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(object), typeof(MyUserControl), new PropertyMetadata(false));
```

Comment: I never thought of this! Thanks for the idea! However, I get the following error at execution time. 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' in ListBox line

Comment: I've fixed the upper, however now I get `The type initializer for 'Billing_Components.BillItem' threw an exception.` if I use `PropertyMetadata(false)` and I get Object reference not set to an instance of an object. if U don't use `PropertyMetadata(false)`

Comment: When I put new BillItem() inside the PropertyMetadata, then I got an empty object.

Answer (score 0):

on the view have an item that inherits from ItemsControl eg listbox, then place your objects in an ObservableCollection property in your VM. then simply bind to that property in the ItemsControl/listbox or whatevers ItemsSource property

ItemSource="{Binding MyObjectCollection}"

Comment: How will that create a UserControl for each object inside the ItemSource?

Comment: I've changed my question, can you review it please?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand why you would want a usercontrol for each item. Would I be correct to presume you want a listbox for each item in your collection to then display it's items? If so you would be better of using a listbox to display all your items then a second listbox that displays the subitems of the selected item in the first listbox.

Comment: UserControl does not contain a listbox, it will contain all kinds of buttons I need for interacting with each line (it's actually a connection to Access DB). Thus I need to forward the object inside the List to the UserControl. I've tried doing what @vlada said, and it works, but renders a default object.

Comment: In that case you need to place your user control inside a ListboxItem template and set the user control to take the object as it's data context. That would allow for it to hook up itself without the need for additional code behind.

Comment: Could you edit your answer to show me how can yo do that?